# PL/SQL NVL function to return any string

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

i wanted to replace :var to any string if it is NULL.

```
SELECT x FROM tbl1 
WHERE x = NVL(:var, '%%')
```

just something like this but the '%%' dont work. what must i do?

Comment: `where x = :var or :var is null` is the usual workaround

Comment: Can column `x` be null? If so, should a null `:var` match rows where `x` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm) condition

> LIKE conditions match a portion of one character value to another by searching the first value for the pattern specified by the second

```
SELECT x FROM tbl1 
WHERE x like NVL(:var, '%%')
```

@William Robertson comment is correct, you don't need multiple (or double) %

> A percent sign (%) in the pattern can match zero or more characters

```
SELECT x FROM tbl1 
WHERE x like NVL(:var, '%')
```

Comment: `'%'` is the usual wildcard for matching any non-null string. I'm not sure what `'%%'` adds.